# Prevent app from accessing mobile network on Android 8?

Tags: mobile-network, 8.0-oreo

I am on Android 8.0.0 and not able to find an option to prevent an app from accessing the mobile network.

Did I just not find it or doesn't this feature exist on version 8 yet?

Comment: Googles main income bases on displaying ads that are loaded from the internet. Guess now why there is no way to completely disable network access for an app (only background internet access can be denied).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an App called [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en_US&gl=US) to accomplish this.

[Deny Access to App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqQKf.png)

Go to Add task > add action > Net > Network Access

It creates a VPN for the chosen app, thereby preventing it from using the real network.

Answer (score 1):

You might wish to take a look at [Firewall apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall#group_377). Depending on whether your device is rooted, the following two candidates are especially recommendable:

#### rooted device: [AFWall+](https://f-droid.org/packages/dev.ukanth.ufirewall/)

(also [available at Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall)¹) This is what I use, and I'm quite satisfied with it:

[image] [image] [image]

Able to access root powers, this is the most complete Firewall solution available. You can even use custom `iptables` rules (I use that e.g. to make sure what DNS provider is contacted when I'm not in my home network). And as the first screenshot shows, you can not only define per-app, or per-interface – but have several more options which are not all shown here, e.g. to prevent an app using data when in roaming, while otherwise permitting it.

#### non-rooted device: [NetGuard](https://f-droid.org/packages/eu.faircode.netguard/)

(also [available at Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard)¹) Like the solution presented by Dan, Netguard uses VPN to tackle the issue. You will easily identify some similarities:

[image] [image] [image]

Like *AFWall+*, NetGuard allows you per-app and per-interface (incl. Roaming) settings. It also offers several additional features worth exploring (some of which are paid – as are some of AFWall+).

Both apps are open-source and have a very good standing. Both are recommended by several security experts, so both are good choices. Specifically for the purpose you were asking, they offer you much easier maintenance and give you easy overview of which app is allowed what (recommended mode in both cases: block all by default, and allow selectively where needed). Tasker of course is a mighty tool as well and kind of a swiss-army-knife – but for this purpose, a dedicated Firewall app is much better suited IMHO.

---

¹ <sub>I always recommend F-Droid as source as apps from there are more privacy-friendly and not crippled to meet Google's restrictions</sub>

Comment: Thanks! What's more battery-efficient? The proper firewall or Tasker?

Comment: Hard to tell – and also depends on the Firewall. With AFWall+, the app is just a GUI for `iptables` – so it just sets up the rules (and lets you maintain them), and you can pretty much neglect the "battery factor". A VPN will always use more juice. NetGuard will run all the time (but cover all your apps) – but then, for full protection there's no way around that. Which again brings it down to "the app is just the GUI", and the rest makes no difference. // I'd test out which suits you best. If not rooted, it won't make much difference battery-wise IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

### Un-Rooted:

Use [**Tracker Control**](https://f-droid.org/repo/net.kollnig.missioncontrol.fdroid_2021051202.apk) from FDroid.
It has many features. But requires a `local VPN` to set up(just like NetGuard).
If you're a privacy enthusiast like me, I'd recommend you using that.

**Main Features it offers:**

- Revoke/Block access to individual apps from trackers.
- Block internet access to apps.
- You can even check where your data goes(Country is highlighted).
- And many more.

### Rooted:

- Use **Adaway** for blocking Ads.
- Afwall+ as Firewall.(It basically uses iptables for blocking internet access).

#### My personal suggestion:

Always buy phones that is community supported, and install custom ROMs like LineageOS which support **firewall**s by default and more private compared to Stock ROMs. And don't forget to **De-Google**.